# sympy: compute lcm() of polynomials without expanding the result

Tags: sympy, lcm

When I compute the LCM of multiple polynomials, the result seems to be always expanded:

```
>>> from sympy import lcm
>>> from sympy.abc import x,y,z
>>> lcm([x+y,y+z,z+x])
x**2*y + x**2*z + x*y**2 + 2*x*y*z + x*z**2 + y**2*z + y*z**2
```

I'd rather get the results as a product, like this:

```
>>> lcm([x+y,y+z,z+x]).factor()
(x + y)*(x + z)*(y + z)
```

Of course, I can (like in the example) use `factor()`, but this requires extra time.  I assume that internally the result first exists as a list of factors and then explicitly expanded.  I'd be fine with that product of factors, prior to expansion.

Is there a way to instruct sympy to hand back such an unexpanded product of factors?

Comment: The internal calculations will use the expanded form so the result is not explicitly expanded at the end.

Comment: Does that mean that the current (expanded) result is the "natural" result for these calculations?

Comment: Yes. You can use factor afterwards if you want (as you showed).